# How to calculate the runtime complexity of an array whose size is related to current index?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I am trying to figure out the runtime complexity of the function below. It finds the prime factors of given number.

```
function test(n){
    n = parseInt(n);

    var factors = [];

    for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        while((n % i) === 0){
            factors.push(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}
```

`while` loop's execution depends on the value of `i` and I have no idea how can I calculate it or should I. This is not O(N2) right?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that your outer `for` loop is `O(n)`.  The tricky part here is your inner `while` loop.  This loop is computing the number of prime factors for a given value of `n`.  So if we had an explicit function, or at least upper bound, to computing prime factors we could just multiply by `n` to get the overall bound.

I found the following two helpful questions on our sister site, Mathematics Stack Exchange:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938204/upper-bound-number-of-distinct-prime-factors
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972003/upper-bound-for-count-of-unique-prime-divisors

They both reveal that an upper bound is:

```
log(n) / log( log(n) )
```

Because your loops are directly nested, we can just multiply the two complexities to arrive at:

```
O(n*log(n) / log(log(n)) )
```

Comment: I started to understand. It is still a little vague, I guess I need to practice. So I can say the result is "O(n*log(n) / log(log(n)) )" ?

Comment: @amone Yes, this is my conclusion after reading those Math stack exchange articles.  You can plot this bound versus both `n` and `n^2` to get a feel for where it is.